# Hide the grid in an a specificaltair plot within a set of vstacked plots

Tags: altair

I am trying to create a plot composed of 2 charts stacked vertically: a time series chart showing a data and below it a time series chart showing texts representing events on the time axis. I want the data-chart having a grid, but the mark_text chart below not to show an outer line and no grid. I use the chart.configure_axis(grid=False) command to hide the axis but get the following error: `Objects with "config" attribute cannot be used within LayerChart. Consider defining the config attribute in the LayerChart object instead.`

I can't figure out, where to apply the  configure_axis(grid=False) option, so it will only apply to the bottom plot. any help on this would be greatly appreciated. or any suggestion how to implement the label-plot in a different way.

here is my code:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import locale
from altair_saver import save
from datetime import datetime

file = '.\lagebericht.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';')

source = df
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "de_CH")
min_date = '2020-02-29'
domain_pd = pd.to_datetime([min_date, '2020-12-1']).astype(int) / 10 ** 6

base = alt.Chart(source, title='Neumeldungen BS').encode(
    alt.X('test_datum:T', axis=alt.Axis(title="",format="%b %y"), scale = alt.Scale(domain=list(domain_pd) ))
    )

bar = base.mark_bar(width = 1).encode(
    alt.Y('faelle_bs:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title="Anzahl Fälle"), scale = alt.Scale(domain=(0, 120)))
    )

line =  base.mark_line(color='blue').encode(
    y='faelle_Total:Q')

chart1 = (bar + line).properties(width=600)

events= pd.DataFrame({
    'datum': [datetime(2020,7,1), datetime(2020,5,15)],
    'const': [1,1],
    'label': ['allgememeiner Lockdown', 'Gruppen > 50 verboten'],
})


base = alt.Chart(events).encode(
    alt.X('datum:T', axis=alt.Axis(title="", format="%b %y"), scale = alt.Scale(domain=list(domain_pd) ))
    )

points =  base.mark_rule(color='blue').encode(
    y=alt.Y('const:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title="",ticks=False, domain=False, labels=False), scale = alt.Scale(domain=(0, 10)))
    )
    
text = base.mark_text(
    align='right',
    baseline='bottom',
    angle = 20,
    dx=0,  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
    dy=20,
).encode(text='label:O').configure_axis(grid=False)

chart2 = (points + text).properties(width=600, height = 50)

save(chart1 & chart2, r"images\figs.html")
```

this is what it looks without the grid=False option:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvkcC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `configure()` method should be thought of as a way to specify a global chart theme; you cannot have different configurations within a single Chart (See https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#global-config-vs-local-config-vs-encoding for a discussion of this).

The way to do what you want is not via global configuration, but via axis settings. For example, you can pass `grid=False` to `alt.Axis`:

```py
points =  alt.Chart(events).mark_rule(color='blue').encode(
    x=alt.X('datum:T', axis=alt.Axis(title="", format="%b %y"), scale = alt.Scale(domain=list(domain_pd) )),
    y=alt.Y('const:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title="",ticks=False, domain=False, labels=False), scale = alt.Scale(domain=(0, 10)))
    )
    
text = alt.Chart(events).mark_text().encode(
    x=alt.X('datum:T', axis=alt.Axis(title="", grid=False, format="%b %y"), scale = alt.Scale(domain=list(domain_pd) )),
    text='label:O'
)
```

Comment: This finally worked. I had tried this in the first place butmust have made a mistake and was heading in the wrong direction to find a solution. Thanks for bringing me back on the right path :-).